# Does evolving a Pokemon change the moves it has?

Tags: pokemon-go

Before I decide on what pokemon I want to evolve, I wanted to pick the one with the moves or tricks I wanted to keep. But I'm unsure if evolving the pokemon will change the moves or tricks that is has so it really does not matter.

Comment: Please, try to pay a little more attention to the tags; you create new ones automatically if they don't match existing ones.

Comment: Btw it's "Pokemon", not "Pokermon". You've misspelled it in your previous question, too.